# Dependent dropdown using appscript

Tags: dropdown

I am using appscript to create 3 dependent dropdowns in the file, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14WNU4DzjDDtaR6w7jTBoBzJJ12jv8tdgpPWpPC0CJiw/edit?usp=sharing.

The 3 dependent dropsowns are dropdowntoLO, dropdownforproduct, and dropdownLOtoproduct

The dropdowntoLO is to populate the columns B and C of the LO sheet from the Dats sheet. While that is happening, on edit, a dropdown is also created in column D. Instead, it has to allow text input. I can do when I remove the Data Validation for column D but that is an irritant.

The dropdownforproduct is to populate columns B and C in the Product_mapping sheet from the Product sheet. However, it is erratic and is showing the dependent values only for one product.

The dropdownLOtoproduct is to populate columns F, G, and H from the LO sheet. It is not happening.

Request help.